# Changing XML Code Folding in ACE Editor

Tags: editor, ace-editor

The current code-folding behavior of the ACE editor is to fold XML from:

```
<TAG DATA=FOO DATA=BAR>
  <blah>
</TAG>
```

into: `<tag ... </tag>`

How can I get it instead to do something more along the lines of:
`<tag data=foo data=bar> ... </tag>`

IE, I want to keep the attributes of the starting tag unfolded. Is there an easy way to do this? What files should I be editing?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this works, at least if I use https://ace.c9.io/build/kitchen-sink.html, switch to XML and use this XML: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tw-message trace='log info' id='id'>
  <offerings/>
</tw-message>

Comment: at least if all properties are inside the same line, will the folding work as you exepect, I think.